# Why is node inefficient with memory when writing a 50MB file to disk with a writable stream?

Tags: node.js, stream, node-streams

I am curious why node.js v14 is struggling to emit a 50MB file. The JS code:

```
const ws = fs.createWriteStream("out_test.pbm", "utf8");
fs.write("P1\n10000 5000\n");
for (let i = 0; i < 10*1000*1000*5; ++i) { ws.write("0"); }
```

This fails without specifying `node --max-old-space-size=8192` to run it.

I'm wondering why the internal logic doesn't periodically take an opportunity to flush rather than somehow inefficiently using more than 4GB of JS heap.

Edit: Is a generator the most natural way to express the logic required to drain the stream? It's awkward otherwise to make the for loop interruptible.

Comment: I couldn't speak on why it works that way, but reading from the documentation, isn't that an improper use of the write() method in the first place? "If false is returned (by the write() method), further attempts to write data to the stream should stop until the 'drain' event is emitted". Also "While calling write() on a stream that is not draining is allowed, Node.js will buffer all written chunks until maximum memory usage occurs, at which point it will abort unconditionally."

Comment: Thanks, I'll add the drain logic to it and see if it improves, hopefully it will improve dramatically. The API is reasonable. But I'm just surprised that theres no safety net built in... In all other implementations of software using streams I've done until now there's enough breathing room for draining to happen. But on this one I'm dumping a simple bitmap data structure to a PBM and it's very efficient, so it's a bit of an edge case.