# Efficient way to apply backpressure logic to a generator?

Tags: javascript, node.js, generator, node-streams

I have been trying to come up with a way to alleviate backpressure in scenarios where I want to write many megabytes or gigabytes from data structures out to the filesystem or network, and doing it naively results in [poor memory usage behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67261766/why-is-node-inefficient-with-memory-when-writing-a-50mb-file-to-disk-with-a-writ).

Here's something I came up with.

```
import stream from "stream";
import fs from "fs";

function* seq() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10 * 1000 * 1000; ++i) yield String(i) + "\n";
}

stream.pipeline(
  stream.Readable.from(seq()),
  fs.createWriteStream("test-generator.log", "utf8"),
  (err) => {
    console.log(err ? "error" : "done");
  }
);
```

This does work, but I feel like it could be made to have better runtime performance.

The generator here represents the source of data from our application, and I leveraged `pipeline` to obtain stream backpressure handling.

I'm pretty sure it can be argued that the generator isn't helpful to the example and I could have golfed the incrementing logic into the Readable, but that `Readable.from` sugar is pretty compelling.

```
❯ time node -r ts-node/register test3.ts                                        
done
node -r ts-node/register test3.ts  9.67s user 1.28s system 129% cpu 8.453 total
```

I've confirmed that it works properly (no buffering related runaway memory problems), now I just feel like this is a bit slow. Yes, it's a 10 million line, 76MB output, a nontrivial amount of data, but I really hope that it's possible to make this less of a bottleneck in terms of throughput. I think it's spending too much time in the CPU, providing under 10MB/s of throughput. I don't think I'd consider this a "good" implementation until it's a hundred or so times faster to keep pace with storage devices.

Node profiling results:

```
Statistical profiling result from isolate-0x5d5b060-10453-v8.log, (8109 ticks, 49 unaccounted, 0 excluded).

 [Shared libraries]:
   ticks  total  nonlib   name
   5444   67.1%          /usr/local/bin/node
    266    3.3%          /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.27.so
      2    0.0%          [vdso]

 [JavaScript]:
   ticks  total  nonlib   name
    347    4.3%   14.5%  LazyCompile: *next internal/streams/from.js:74:22
    340    4.2%   14.2%  LazyCompile: *ondata internal/streams/readable.js:717:18
    249    3.1%   10.4%  LazyCompile: *readableAddChunk internal/streams/readable.js:231:26
    195    2.4%    8.1%  LazyCompile: *fromString buffer.js:444:20
    123    1.5%    5.1%  LazyCompile: *seq /home/slu/Documents/entropy-dynamics/faa/test3.ts:8:14
     76    0.9%    3.2%  LazyCompile: *emit events.js:264:44
     57    0.7%    2.4%  LazyCompile: *WriteStream._writev internal/fs/streams.js:416:41
     51    0.6%    2.1%  LazyCompile: *EventEmitter.emit domain.js:456:39
     11    0.1%    0.5%  LazyCompile: *<anonymous> internal/fs/utils.js:636:45
      8    0.1%    0.3%  LazyCompile: *scan /home/slu/Documents/entropy-dynamics/faa/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:10708:22
      6    0.1%    0.3%  LazyCompile: *writev fs.js:717:16
      5    0.1%    0.2%  LazyCompile: *bindWorker /home/slu/Documents/entropy-dynamics/faa/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:42602:28
      4    0.0%    0.2%  LazyCompile: *processTicksAndRejections internal/process/task_queues.js:65:35
      4    0.0%    0.2%  LazyCompile: *parseJSDocCommentWorker /home/slu/Documents/entropy-dynamics/faa/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:34575:45
      4    0.0%    0.2%  LazyCompile: *<anonymous> /home/slu/Documents/entropy-dynamics/faa/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:34592:74
      3    0.0%    0.1%  LazyCompile: *scanJsDocToken /home/slu/Documents/entropy-dynamics/faa/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:11431:32
      2    0.0%    0.1%  LazyCompile: *onwrite internal/streams/writable.js:394:17
      2    0.0%    0.1%  LazyCompile: *nextTick internal/process/task_queues.js:101:18
      2    0.0%    0.1%  LazyCompile: *declareSymbol /home/slu/Documents/entropy-dynamics/faa/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:40668:31
      2    0.0%    0.1%  LazyCompile: *bindChildren /home/slu/Documents/entropy-dynamics/faa/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:40973:30
      2    0.0%    0.1%  LazyCompile: *bind /home/slu/Documents/entropy-dynamics/faa/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:42512:22
      1    0.0%    0.0%  RegExp: (\slib\s*=\s*)('|")(.+?)\2
      1    0.0%    0.0%  LazyCompile: *visitNode /home/slu/Documents/entropy-dynamics/faa/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:28207:23
      1    0.0%    0.0%  LazyCompile: *setContextFlag /home/slu/Documents/entropy-dynamics/faa/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:29293:32
      1    0.0%    0.0%  LazyCompile: *scanString /home/slu/Documents/entropy-dynamics/faa/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:10343:28
      1    0.0%    0.0%  LazyCompile: *scanIdentifier /home/slu/Documents/entropy-dynamics/faa/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:11172:32
      1    0.0%    0.0%  LazyCompile: *parseStatement /home/slu/Documents/entropy-dynamics/faa/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:33466:32
      1    0.0%    0.0%  LazyCompile: *parsePropertyOrMethodSignature /home/slu/Documents/entropy-dynamics/faa/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:30933:48
      1    0.0%    0.0%  LazyCompile: *parseParameterWorker /home/slu/Documents/entropy-dynamics/faa/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:30759:38
      1    0.0%    0.0%  LazyCompile: *parseDelimitedList /home/slu/Documents/entropy-dynamics/faa/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:30342:36
      1    0.0%    0.0%  LazyCompile: *normalizeString path.js:52:25
      1    0.0%    0.0%  LazyCompile: *nextToken /home/slu/Documents/entropy-dynamics/faa/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:29434:27
      1    0.0%    0.0%  LazyCompile: *modifiersToFlags /home/slu/Documents/entropy-dynamics/faa/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:17966:30
      1    0.0%    0.0%  LazyCompile: *iterateCommentRanges /home/slu/Documents/entropy-dynamics/faa/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:9928:34
      1    0.0%    0.0%  LazyCompile: *isLeftHandSideExpressionKind /home/slu/Documents/entropy-dynamics/faa/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:13005:42
      1    0.0%    0.0%  LazyCompile: *isExportSpecifier /home/slu/Documents/entropy-dynamics/faa/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:27185:31
      1    0.0%    0.0%  LazyCompile: *hasDynamicName /home/slu/Documents/entropy-dynamics/faa/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:16495:28
      1    0.0%    0.0%  LazyCompile: *getSyntacticModifierFlagsNoCache /home/slu/Documents/entropy-dynamics/faa/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:17958:46
      1    0.0%    0.0%  LazyCompile: *get internal/streams/writable.js:698:8
      1    0.0%    0.0%  LazyCompile: *forEachChild /home/slu/Documents/entropy-dynamics/faa/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:28244:26
      1    0.0%    0.0%  LazyCompile: *createToken /home/slu/Documents/entropy-dynamics/faa/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:21424:29
      1    0.0%    0.0%  LazyCompile: *createNodeArray /home/slu/Documents/entropy-dynamics/faa/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:29620:33
      1    0.0%    0.0%  LazyCompile: *createNodeArray /home/slu/Documents/entropy-dynamics/faa/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:21143:33
      1    0.0%    0.0%  LazyCompile: *createBaseGenericNamedDeclaration /home/slu/Documents/entropy-dynamics/faa/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:21210:51
      1    0.0%    0.0%  LazyCompile: *codePointAt /home/slu/Documents/entropy-dynamics/faa/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:11595:63
      1    0.0%    0.0%  LazyCompile: *bindParameter /home/slu/Documents/entropy-dynamics/faa/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:43358:31
      1    0.0%    0.0%  LazyCompile: *bindEach /home/slu/Documents/entropy-dynamics/faa/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:40963:26
      1    0.0%    0.0%  LazyCompile: *appendIfUnique /home/slu/Documents/entropy-dynamics/faa/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:1226:28

 [C++]:
   ticks  total  nonlib   name
    589    7.3%   24.6%  epoll_pwait
     51    0.6%    2.1%  __GI___pthread_getspecific
     48    0.6%    2.0%  __pthread_cond_timedwait
     26    0.3%    1.1%  __GI___pthread_mutex_lock
     16    0.2%    0.7%  cfree
     16    0.2%    0.7%  __pthread_cond_signal
     11    0.1%    0.5%  write
     11    0.1%    0.5%  mprotect
      8    0.1%    0.3%  __libc_malloc
      8    0.1%    0.3%  __GI___pthread_mutex_unlock
      7    0.1%    0.3%  munmap
      6    0.1%    0.3%  __lll_lock_wait
      5    0.1%    0.2%  __lll_unlock_wake
      4    0.0%    0.2%  std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long)
      4    0.0%    0.2%  fwrite
      3    0.0%    0.1%  std::ostream::sentry::~sentry()
      3    0.0%    0.1%  mmap
      2    0.0%    0.1%  do_futex_wait.constprop.1
      2    0.0%    0.1%  _IO_file_xsputn
      1    0.0%    0.0%  sysconf
      1    0.0%    0.0%  std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::allocator<char> const&)
      1    0.0%    0.0%  std::ostream::sentry::sentry(std::ostream&)
      1    0.0%    0.0%  sigemptyset
      1    0.0%    0.0%  sigaddset
      1    0.0%    0.0%  __printf_fp
      1    0.0%    0.0%  __libc_write
      1    0.0%    0.0%  _IO_file_sync

 [Summary]:
   ticks  total  nonlib   name
   1520   18.7%   63.4%  JavaScript
    828   10.2%   34.5%  C++
    656    8.1%   27.4%  GC
   5712   70.4%          Shared libraries
     49    0.6%          Unaccounted

 [C++ entry points]:
   ticks    cpp   total   name
     50   42.7%    0.6%  __GI___pthread_getspecific
     21   17.9%    0.3%  __GI___pthread_mutex_lock
      8    6.8%    0.1%  write
      8    6.8%    0.1%  __libc_malloc
      8    6.8%    0.1%  __GI___pthread_mutex_unlock
      4    3.4%    0.0%  std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long)
      4    3.4%    0.0%  fwrite
      3    2.6%    0.0%  std::ostream::sentry::~sentry()
      3    2.6%    0.0%  mprotect
      2    1.7%    0.0%  _IO_file_xsputn
      1    0.9%    0.0%  std::ostream::sentry::sentry(std::ostream&)
      1    0.9%    0.0%  cfree
      1    0.9%    0.0%  __pthread_cond_signal
      1    0.9%    0.0%  __lll_lock_wait
      1    0.9%    0.0%  __libc_write
      1    0.9%    0.0%  _IO_file_sync

 [Bottom up (heavy) profile]:
  Note: percentage shows a share of a particular caller in the total
  amount of its parent calls.
  Callers occupying less than 1.0% are not shown.

   ticks parent  name
   5444   67.1%  /usr/local/bin/node
   1343   24.7%    /usr/local/bin/node
    436   32.5%      /usr/local/bin/node
    426   97.7%        LazyCompile: *seq /home/slu/Documents/entropy-dynamics/faa/test3.ts:8:14
    426  100.0%          /usr/local/bin/node
    425   99.8%            LazyCompile: *next internal/streams/from.js:74:22
    433   32.2%      LazyCompile: ~writev fs.js:717:16
    432   99.8%        LazyCompile: *WriteStream._writev internal/fs/streams.js:416:41
    275   63.7%          LazyCompile: ~doWrite internal/streams/writable.js:367:17
    275  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~clearBuffer internal/streams/writable.js:493:21
    157   36.3%          LazyCompile: *onwrite internal/streams/writable.js:394:17
    157  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~<anonymous> internal/fs/streams.js:396:60
     82    6.1%      LazyCompile: *seq /home/slu/Documents/entropy-dynamics/faa/test3.ts:8:14
     82  100.0%        /usr/local/bin/node
     82  100.0%          LazyCompile: *next internal/streams/from.js:74:22
     82  100.0%            LazyCompile: *next internal/streams/from.js:74:22
     78    5.8%      LazyCompile: *next internal/streams/from.js:74:22
     74   94.9%        LazyCompile: *next internal/streams/from.js:74:22
     74  100.0%          /usr/local/bin/node
      4    5.1%        /usr/local/bin/node
     72    5.4%      LazyCompile: ~wrapSafe internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:964:18
     72  100.0%        LazyCompile: ~Module._compile internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1017:37
     72  100.0%          LazyCompile: ~Module._extensions..js internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:37
     72  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~Module.load internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:916:33
     19    1.4%      LazyCompile: ~compileForInternalLoader internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:270:27
     17   89.5%        LazyCompile: ~nativeModuleRequire internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:303:29
      3   17.6%          Eval: ~<anonymous> repl.js:1:1
      3  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~compileForInternalLoader internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:270:27
      2   11.8%          Eval: ~<anonymous> stream.js:1:1
      2  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~compileForInternalLoader internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:270:27
      2   11.8%          Eval: ~<anonymous> internal/modules/esm/loader.js:1:1
      2  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~compileForInternalLoader internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:270:27
      2   11.8%          Eval: ~<anonymous> internal/bootstrap/node.js:1:1
      1    5.9%          LazyCompile: ~setupPrepareStackTrace internal/bootstrap/node.js:252:32
      1  100.0%            Eval: ~<anonymous> internal/bootstrap/node.js:1:1
      1    5.9%          Eval: ~<anonymous> tty.js:1:1
      1  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~compileForInternalLoader internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:270:27
      1    5.9%          Eval: ~<anonymous> internal/url.js:1:1
      1  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~compileForInternalLoader internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:270:27
      1    5.9%          Eval: ~<anonymous> internal/source_map/source_map_cache.js:1:1
      1  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~compileForInternalLoader internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:270:27
      1    5.9%          Eval: ~<anonymous> internal/process/task_queues.js:1:1
      1  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~compileForInternalLoader internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:270:27
      1    5.9%          Eval: ~<anonymous> internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1:1
      1  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~compileForInternalLoader internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:270:27
      1    5.9%          Eval: ~<anonymous> events.js:1:1
      1  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~compileForInternalLoader internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:270:27
      1    5.9%          Eval: ~<anonymous> buffer.js:1:1
      1  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~compileForInternalLoader internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:270:27
      2   10.5%        LazyCompile: ~compileForPublicLoader internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:219:25
      2  100.0%          LazyCompile: ~loadNativeModule internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:31:26
      2  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~Module._load internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:704:24
   1182   21.7%    LazyCompile: *fromString buffer.js:444:20
   1182  100.0%      LazyCompile: *ondata internal/streams/readable.js:717:18
   1182  100.0%        LazyCompile: *emit events.js:264:44
   1182  100.0%          LazyCompile: *EventEmitter.emit domain.js:456:39
   1180   99.8%            LazyCompile: *readableAddChunk internal/streams/readable.js:231:26
    736   13.5%    LazyCompile: *next internal/streams/from.js:74:22
    406   55.2%      LazyCompile: *next internal/streams/from.js:74:22
    406  100.0%        /usr/local/bin/node
    329   44.7%      /usr/local/bin/node
    188    3.5%    LazyCompile: *writev fs.js:717:16
    188  100.0%      LazyCompile: *WriteStream._writev internal/fs/streams.js:416:41
    188  100.0%        LazyCompile: *onwrite internal/streams/writable.js:394:17
    188  100.0%          LazyCompile: ~<anonymous> internal/fs/streams.js:396:60
    188  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~wrapper fs.js:636:19
    169    3.1%    LazyCompile: *ondata internal/streams/readable.js:717:18
    169  100.0%      LazyCompile: *emit events.js:264:44
    169  100.0%        LazyCompile: *EventEmitter.emit domain.js:456:39
    168   99.4%          LazyCompile: *readableAddChunk internal/streams/readable.js:231:26
    168  100.0%            LazyCompile: *next internal/streams/from.js:74:22
    152    2.8%    LazyCompile: *EventEmitter.emit domain.js:456:39
    152  100.0%      LazyCompile: *readableAddChunk internal/streams/readable.js:231:26
    152  100.0%        LazyCompile: *next internal/streams/from.js:74:22
    152  100.0%          /usr/local/bin/node
    138    2.5%    LazyCompile: *readableAddChunk internal/streams/readable.js:231:26
    138  100.0%      LazyCompile: *next internal/streams/from.js:74:22
    138  100.0%        /usr/local/bin/node

    589    7.3%  epoll_pwait

    347    4.3%  LazyCompile: *next internal/streams/from.js:74:22
    257   74.1%    /usr/local/bin/node
     90   25.9%    LazyCompile: *next internal/streams/from.js:74:22
     90  100.0%      /usr/local/bin/node

    340    4.2%  LazyCompile: *ondata internal/streams/readable.js:717:18
    319   93.8%    LazyCompile: *emit events.js:264:44
    319  100.0%      LazyCompile: *EventEmitter.emit domain.js:456:39
    319  100.0%        LazyCompile: *readableAddChunk internal/streams/readable.js:231:26
    319  100.0%          LazyCompile: *next internal/streams/from.js:74:22
    319  100.0%            /usr/local/bin/node
     21    6.2%    LazyCompile: *EventEmitter.emit domain.js:456:39
     21  100.0%      LazyCompile: *readableAddChunk internal/streams/readable.js:231:26
     21  100.0%        LazyCompile: *next internal/streams/from.js:74:22
     21  100.0%          /usr/local/bin/node

    266    3.3%  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.27.so
    152   57.1%    /usr/local/bin/node
    136   89.5%      /usr/local/bin/node
    133   97.8%        LazyCompile: *seq /home/slu/Documents/entropy-dynamics/faa/test3.ts:8:14
    133  100.0%          /usr/local/bin/node
    133  100.0%            LazyCompile: *next internal/streams/from.js:74:22
      6    3.9%      LazyCompile: *ondata internal/streams/readable.js:717:18
      6  100.0%        LazyCompile: *emit events.js:264:44
      6  100.0%          LazyCompile: *EventEmitter.emit domain.js:456:39
      6  100.0%            LazyCompile: *readableAddChunk internal/streams/readable.js:231:26
      2    1.3%      LazyCompile: *createPool buffer.js:158:20
      2  100.0%        LazyCompile: *fromString buffer.js:444:20
      2  100.0%          LazyCompile: *ondata internal/streams/readable.js:717:18
      2  100.0%            LazyCompile: *emit events.js:264:44
     89   33.5%    LazyCompile: *fromString buffer.js:444:20
     89  100.0%      LazyCompile: *ondata internal/streams/readable.js:717:18
     89  100.0%        LazyCompile: *emit events.js:264:44
     89  100.0%          LazyCompile: *EventEmitter.emit domain.js:456:39
     89  100.0%            LazyCompile: *readableAddChunk internal/streams/readable.js:231:26
      8    3.0%    LazyCompile: *writev fs.js:717:16
      8  100.0%      LazyCompile: *WriteStream._writev internal/fs/streams.js:416:41
      8  100.0%        LazyCompile: *onwrite internal/streams/writable.js:394:17
      8  100.0%          LazyCompile: ~<anonymous> internal/fs/streams.js:396:60
      8  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~wrapper fs.js:636:19

    249    3.1%  LazyCompile: *readableAddChunk internal/streams/readable.js:231:26
    210   84.3%    LazyCompile: *next internal/streams/from.js:74:22
    210  100.0%      /usr/local/bin/node
     39   15.7%    /usr/local/bin/node

    195    2.4%  LazyCompile: *fromString buffer.js:444:20
    173   88.7%    LazyCompile: *ondata internal/streams/readable.js:717:18
    173  100.0%      LazyCompile: *emit events.js:264:44
    173  100.0%        LazyCompile: *EventEmitter.emit domain.js:456:39
    173  100.0%          LazyCompile: *readableAddChunk internal/streams/readable.js:231:26
    173  100.0%            LazyCompile: *next internal/streams/from.js:74:22
     22   11.3%    LazyCompile: *emit events.js:264:44
     22  100.0%      LazyCompile: *EventEmitter.emit domain.js:456:39
     22  100.0%        LazyCompile: *readableAddChunk internal/streams/readable.js:231:26
     22  100.0%          LazyCompile: *next internal/streams/from.js:74:22
     22  100.0%            /usr/local/bin/node

    123    1.5%  LazyCompile: *seq /home/slu/Documents/entropy-dynamics/faa/test3.ts:8:14
    104   84.6%    /usr/local/bin/node
    104  100.0%      LazyCompile: *next internal/streams/from.js:74:22
    104  100.0%        LazyCompile: *next internal/streams/from.js:74:22
    104  100.0%          /usr/local/bin/node
     19   15.4%    LazyCompile: *next internal/streams/from.js:74:22
     19  100.0%      LazyCompile: *next internal/streams/from.js:74:22
     19  100.0%        /usr/local/bin/node
```

Comment: Did you do profiling? Where does the code execution spend most of its time?

Comment: I doubt this has anything to do with backpressure. I'd try increasing the chunk size of the stream.

Comment: It's not related to backpressure, no. Having backpressure not dealt with wouldnt work for the use case (in which I'm writing a 2 dimensional PBM bitmap file containing 233 million characters) as the machine would run out of memory. But the limiting issue is CPU time, it's going to take it around 4 minutes to run. I'll try to profile.

Comment: Updated with profile results.

Comment: I also have to mention, in my application I have a Uint8Array that I want to represent in an ASCII file format, this can be done efficiently using traditional methods. And I will do that in my code. But, the question is, could we make streams perform a bit better? I was hoping I could do something with the new language features to get backpressure management for writing out large files.

Comment: From loosely interpreting the profiling results I'm going to go out on a limb and say that it seems like this is just the throughput we can expect to get.